# How to prove these statements?

Tags: uniform-convergence

Let $K: R → [0, ∞) $ be continuous, and suppose that $\int_RK(x) dx = 1$.

> (1) Prove that for any bounded $f ∈ C(R)$ :
>
> $lim_{t\rightarrow ∞} \int_Rf(x − y)tK(ty)dy = f(x)$ for all $x \in R$.
>
> (2) Show that the convergence is uniform if $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Can anyone give me some clue on how to prove these statements?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substitution $u = ty$. Thus $ \int f(x-y)K(ty)t\mathrm{d}y = \int f(x-\frac{u}{t}) K(u) \mathrm{d}u$. As $\int K(u)\mathrm{d}u = 1$, write :
\begin{align}
f(x) = f(x) \cdot 1 = f(x) \int K(u)\mathrm{d}u = \int f(x)K(u)\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}

Substract the two terms :
\begin{align}
\int f\left(x-\frac{u}{t}\right) K(u) \mathrm{d}u - f(x) = \int \left(f\left(x-\frac{u}{t}\right) - f(x)\right) K(u) \mathrm{d}u
\end{align}

$f$ is bounded by a constant $C>0$. $K$ is integrable, thus there exists $A >0$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus [-A,A]} K(u) \mathrm{d}u < \frac{\varepsilon}{4C}$.

$f$ is continuous at $x$ so there exists $\delta$ such that if $|x-y| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Now you can complete the proof :

\begin{align}
\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(f\left(x-\frac{u}{t}\right) - f(x)\right) K(u) \mathrm{d}u \right| &\leqslant \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left|\left(f\left(x-\frac{u}{t}\right) - f(x)\right) K(u)\right| \mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
Divide the right hand side in two integrals over $[-A,A]$ and its complement. Use what is stated above while carefully choosing $A$ and $\delta$ and controlling $t$. Thus you have $<\varepsilon$ which is a proof of convergence.

For the uniform convergence : prove $\delta$ can be uniformly choosen so that what you did before does not depend on $x$ actually.

Comment: Thanks so much! It's really straightforward! But could you please elaborate how to chose such A? Because I notice that u is depends on t. I wanna to let t goes infinite but the u/t also goes infinite. Could you please give me some guide on how to chose A and controlling t? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $K$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$, which means that $\sup \int_I K < \infty$ where the supremum is taken over all compact intervals of $\mathbb{R}$. The supremum is by definition its integral over $\mathbb{R}$. Thus if $\varepsilon$ is fixed, there exists a compact interval $[-A,A]$ such that $|\int_[-A,A] K - \int_{\mathbb{R}}K |< \varepsilon$ (that is it is close enough to the supremum.

If $A$ is fixed, then for the integral over $[-A,A]$, $u/t$ lives in [-A/|t|, A/|t|] which become very little with $t$ expanding to infinity.

The technical thing is ordering your inequalities.

Comment: Thanks so much! I got that!